# Azure ML Studio: OSError: Cannot save file into a non-existent directory

Tags: python, azure, azure-machine-learning-service, oserror

I am using `Azure ML Studio` to read data from a csv file by creating a data asset `test5` and write data into a csv file for my current working directory (which is failing). I am submitting a Job using a `Compute Cluster` and a `Custom Environment` and I am following the instructions from [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/tutorial-azure-ml-in-a-day) tutorial.

I have written the code in a notebook as:

```
 from azure.ai.ml import MLClient
 from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
 credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
 ml_client = MLClient(
     credential=credential,
     subscription_id="abc",
     resource_group_name="xyz",
     workspace_name="pqr",
 )
 from azure.ai.ml import command
 from azure.ai.ml import Input
    
 registered_model_name = "read_data"
 env_name = "docker-context"
 job = command(inputs=dict(data=Input(type="uri_file",path="azureml:test5:1",),
         registered_model_name=registered_model_name
     ),   
     code="./src/",g
     command="python main.py --data ${<!-- -->{inputs.data}} --registered_model_name ${<!-- -->{inputs.registered_model_name}}",
     environment="docker-context:10",
     compute="amlcluster01",
     experiment_name="read_data1",
     display_name="read_data2",
     )
 ml_client.create_or_update(job)
```

This works fine. The content of the `main.py` file is:

```
 import os
 import argparse
 import pandas as pd
    
 def main():
     print("Hello")
      # input and output arguments
     parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
     parser.add_argument("--data", type=str, help="path to input data")
     parser.add_argument("--registered_model_name", type=str, help="model name")
     args = parser.parse_args()
     print(" ".join(f"{k}={v}" for k, v in vars(args).items()))
     print("input data:", args.data)
     read_data=pd.read_csv(args.data)
     #read_data=pd.read_parquet(args.data, engine='pyarrow')
     #credit_df = pd.read_excel(args.data, header=1, index_col=0)
     print(read_data)
     read_data.to_csv(r'/home/azureuser/cloudfiles/code/Users/Ankit19.Gupta/azureml-in-a-day/src/file3.csv')
    
     print("Hello World !")
    
 if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()
```

Here, all lines of code work fine except `read_data.to_csv(r'/home/azureuser/cloudfiles/code/Users/Ankit19.Gupta/azureml-in-a-day/src/file3.csv')`.

It shows the error message as: `OSError: Cannot save file into a non-existent directory:/home/azureuser/cloudfiles/code/Users/Ankit19.Gupta/azureml-in-a-day/src`.

Can anyone please help me how to save dataframe into a csv file into my current working directory through a Job. Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit:** As msamsami mentioned the code in the answer, when I replace `read_data.to_csv(r'/home/azureuser/cloudfiles/code/Users/Ankit19.Gupta/azureml-in-a-day/src/file3.csv')` with

```
file_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'file3.csv')
read_data.to_csv(file_path)
print(f"read_data saved to {file_path}")
```

I get the following output of the above print statement:

```
read_data saved to /mnt/azureml/cr/j/28bec1ee580a400894b48e5d8576f6ca/exe/wd/file3.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that the directory you wish to save the CSV into doesn't exist. So, to make sure that everything is right, you should make sure that there exist an "azureml-in-a-day" folder under "Ankit19.Gupta", and the same for "src" under "azureml-in-a-day".

Also, try this:

```py
import os

...

file_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'file3.csv')
read_data.to_csv(file_path)

print(f"read_data saved to {file_path}")
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the answer. I have already created these folders in Azure ML workspace but when I submit the job, it goes to a different path on cloud and saved the file in that working directory. By using your code, I can see the path for the current working directory on cloud but I am unable to access it through terminal and so, I am unable to save this file for my Azure ML Workspace within `src` directory. Could you please help ?

Comment: @ankit please share the output of the print in the code I shared (the path in which the app is running)

Comment: I have edited the question. Could you please check the end part of the question ?